# Count colored cells refresh results

Tags: google-apps-script

The coding I have for a google sheet counts coloured cells fine, but i need to be able to refresh the results as soon as the background colour changes, rather than cut and paste to force the result.

I looked at this: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/69722/how-do-i-refresh-script-results-when-a-cell-color-is-changed
Problem is, being a greenhorn, I couldn't work out how to use the count coloured cells scrip, let alone the script to force an update/refresh.

Therefore, I'm looking for a force refresh with the code I already have.

Here is the code that I've used without any problems:

```
function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeformula = activeRg.getFormula();
  var countRangeAddress = activeformula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop().trim();
  var backGrounds = activeSht.getRange(countRangeAddress).getBackgrounds();
  var colorRefAddress = activeformula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop().trim();
  var BackGround = activeSht.getRange(colorRefAddress).getBackground();
  var countCells = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < backGrounds.length; i++)
    for (var k = 0; k < backGrounds[i].length; k++)
      if ( backGrounds[i][k] == BackGround )
        countCells = countCells + 1;
  return countCells;
};
```

Would be really grateful for any help. Many thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the possible event objects [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Answer (score 0):

You're taking in the variables `countRange` and `colorRef` when you call with `countColouredCells()` but they're not used so they're there meaninglessly. You can remove these from your function call:

```
function countColouredCells(){
  //...
}
```

Also, Apps Script has a built-in `onEdit()` function which once defined in your script file, will run every time a value in the sheet is edited. This will only work on a cell velue edit however, and not just from a background colour change. At current there is no way of getting a script to run automatically just from the change of the background colour of a cell.

The `e` parameter of the `onEdit(e)` function however does contain information about the edit that's been made - including the range of cells that were just edited. You can add an `onEdit(e)` function to the file bound to your sheet and use this to pass the parameters you need to `countColouredCells(countRange)`:

```
function onEdit(e){
  countColouredCells(e.range);
}

function countColoredCells(countRange) {
  var activeRg = countRange;
  var activeSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeformula = activeRg.getFormula();
  var countRangeAddress = activeformula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop().trim();
  var backGrounds = activeSht.getRange(countRangeAddress).getBackgrounds();
  var colorRefAddress = activeformula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop().trim();
  var BackGround = activeSht.getRange(colorRefAddress).getBackground();
  var countCells = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < backGrounds.length; i++)
    for (var k = 0; k < backGrounds[i].length; k++)
      if ( backGrounds[i][k] == BackGround )
        countCells = countCells + 1;
  return countCells;
};
```

Where `e.range` is the range of cells edited in the sheet to cause the `onEdit(e)` function to trigger.

Comment: Thanks for getting back with an answer. When I enter the script I get: TypeError: Cannot call method "getFormula" of undefined. (line 8, file "countbycolor")Dismiss. In the sheet itself I get: TypeError: Cannot find function getFormula in object ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,. (line 8). Remember, I have little understanding of the script, I'm just entering what you gave me. Cheers.

Comment: Can you share a copy of your sheet? Having a publically available copy will be helpful to help solve the issue but also is good for community documentation. Make sure to sanitise it if there is any personal information first, though.

Comment: Sorry about the delay getting back. Thanks for your answer. I decided to go with using the drop down data validation option. Entering text values eg. blue, green, which once entered into the box are used to colour the cells through the conditional formatting. The act of using the data validation instantly triggers the count coloured cells script. I don't have to see any text in the coloured cells as that can can be made invisible through conditional formatting too. Again, many thanks for your help.